# Not able to access HTTPS link. Getting ssl connection error?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4

As i have enabled default-ssl site in my ubuntu linux server. And browser showing ssl connection error.

As i have check log file of apache2. Which say **suhosin-path mod_ssl**

```
[Fri Apr 04 16:29:33 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.14.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

FYI, 
**when i run command "apachectl -S" i get this error**

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

**if i run "apachectl configtest"**

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK
```

**EDIT 1**
I am getting below error also

```
Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the error you receive from browsers? We need some more details there please

Answer (score 0):

The request method mentioned in the error message is binary data. It should have been a text string. This could be happening due to sending binary data to a port, which expects a text based protocol.

In your case that probably means the port is configured as an `http` port on the server, but the client connects to that port number and starts talking `https`.

To find out if this is due to a problem on the client or the server, we need to see the URL and the vhost configuration from the server.